# Calling C function from Python with ctypes: errors using pointers

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm calling a C function from a Python 3.4 script using ctypes on Windows 8. I created a DLL with cygwin gcc. The C function works fine as long as I use only parameters and local variables, but any reference with a pointer defined in the function fails (no error message or core file, just a silent program crash). For example, the following fails:

```
CALC_Z_SER_DLL int calc_z_ser(struct complex_num *q, int *output,
                              int len_q, int maxiter) {
    int *malloctest = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *malloctest = 42;  /* crashes here */
```

However, I can access array parameters using pointers with no problem.

Is there a special pointer type I need to use in a Windows DLL? Or some Windows-specific options I need to use when building the DLL? In the header file for the C function, I used this declaration:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_CALC_Z_SER_DLL
#define CALC_Z_SER_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CALC_Z_SER_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

int CALC_Z_SER_DLL calc_z_ser(struct complex_num *q, int *output,
                              int len_q, int maxiter);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe it is a bad example, but in the code you are not accessing a parameter at all, but access allocated memory. Did the `malloc()` succeed? What happens when the called "pointer method" is empty, i.e. does it crash without code, too?

Comment: @dhke, as I said, I can access array parameters using pointers with no problem. But any other use of a pointer fails (for example, passing the address of a local variable to a called C function).  In this example, malloc succeeds, *malloctest causes a crash. 

    >gcc --version
    gcc (GCC) 4.9.3

Comment: @eryksun, gcc 4.9.3 doesn't recognize -mno-cygwin. Apparently it was deprecated and finally removed.

Comment: If you're linking to cygwin1.dll, offhand I don't know how its `malloc` is implemented. msvcrt.dll simply wraps the Win32 heap API. It uses a private heap from [`HeapCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366599). A process also has a default heap that you can try: `HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, sizeof(int))`.